Ubuntu studio 24.04 / UMC 202hd issue
I have some troubles trying to set up my soundcard with Ubuntu studio.
Soundcard is a behringer UMC202hd.
I manage to hear output sounds (like YouTube video sound for instance) but can't find the way to set up my input signal properly.
When sending audio signal to the soundcard jack input, the card's led shows that a signal is received, but I have no audio in the Ubuntu control panel and don't hear anything...
Any idea ?
Thanks for your help, I'm new to Ubuntu studio...
